# Query Execution Details

Tags: sql-server, query, statistics

We need to find out the list of queries which were executed between a from time and to time, which user had executed the query and what was the execution time of that query.

Comment: You want to start monitoring it, or you want the find the queries that have been executed already?

Comment: queries that have executed already.

Comment: You forgot to tag the software you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But almost certainly without enabling that first, you're not going to be able to retrieve that information after the fact.

Comment: We are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

A big problem if you don't have any monitoring set up is that your cached data wont stay forever. Which means you can't go as far back as you want.

The only way to reliably query this (in the future that is) is to set up some monitoring that captures queries that are being fired on your server.

To monitor a server I often setup a really easy WhoIsActive job, that just runs every minute. ( timing will be different on case by case basis )
This will capture anything from the statement, to the login, the database query plan..
It's rather simple, just set up a job that runs the WhoIsActive procedure every X minutes between the times you want, and let it log to a table.

The following 2 links will help you with everything you need to know how to set it up.

[How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/)
[Logging Activity Using sp_WhoIsActive – Take 2](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/)

If you'd like to know more about the WhoIsActive procedure, you can find everything in [this](http://whoisactive.com/docs/) link.

If you're running on a SQL2016 instance I also recommend you to setup your querystore, which will capture all, or most (config setting AUTO vs ALL) queries fired on your database. Which will give you a lot of detail of what's happening on your databases.

Comment: How can you possibly answer this question without knowing which DBMS they are using? The first two sentences apply, the rest is only applicable if the user is using SQL Server. They might be using MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, ...

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you ? **Just for Microsoft SQL Server**

Queries executed between specific dates

```
SELECT
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], 
    dest.TEXT AS [Query]
 FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
    WHERE
     deqs.last_execution_time between '2019-10-22 9:00:00.000' -- start time
                                       and '2019-10-23 16:00:00.000' -- end time
    ORDER BY 
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

**Edit:**

Result is like this :

```
Time                       |  Query 
2019-10-22 23:05:17.033    |  Select * from db_name
.
.
```

And if you want to see who is executing queries I refer you to this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/231836/122901) :

> You would need to start logging account activity of accounts that you don't trust to a table for a complete list. All of the other options (like querying dmvs) will give you temporal data and there's no guarantee that it is complete.

Comment: The challenge with this query it gives the last execution timestamp of a particular query. What we are looking forward to is if we have run the same query 10 times today, when did the query execution start and when did it end, how much time did it take to execute, for all the 10 iterations.

Comment: How can you possibly answer this question without knowing which DBMS they are using?

Comment: @Colin'tHart You are right, I edit my answer this is just for SQL Server.